# Where to start with turtlebot?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I start to learn ros and have the turtlebot. I did all tutorials and don't know how to go on.
*I have an assignment - turtlebot have to scan a figure from paper and after it must search the figure in the room, move to this figure and stop nearly.*

As I understand, turtlebot have a ready base controller, navigation, odomentry and so on, I don't need creating it myself, in bringup minimal I saw this packages and used. But I don't understand how to use it separately, and I couldn't find their sources. Personally, I think to write node for global control, but also can't figure out what topics I need publish, subscribre, what services i need, what I must to write myself and what I can use ready-prepared?

I hope my questions is clear, if not asking please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132896/where-to-start-with-turtlebot?/) by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-02-25**:
write more clear about you taks

**Comment by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) on 2014-02-25**:
I suggest [http://www.cse.sc.edu/~jokane/agitr/](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

take a look this. http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_node
This tells you what topic you need to use to control mobile base.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kirill_Sokolov](https://answers.ros.org/users/4634/kirill_sokolov/) on 2014-02-26**:
Thanks, it can help me